# Insert list-initialized pair into std::map

Tags: c++, insert, stdmap, std-pair, list-initialization

I'm trying to insert a move-only type into a map. I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <map>

class Moveable
{
public:
    Moveable() = default;
    Moveable(const Moveable&) = delete;
    Moveable(Moveable&&) = default;
    Moveable& operator=(const Moveable&) = delete;
    Moveable& operator=(Moveable&&) = default;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int,Moveable> my_map;
    Moveable my_moveable_1, my_moveable_2, my_moveable_3;
    my_map.insert(std::pair<int,Moveable>{1, std::move(my_moveable_1)}); // (1)
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(2, std::move(my_moveable_2)));          // (2)
    my_map.insert({3, std::move(my_moveable_3)});                        // (3)

    return 0;
}
```

What happens is that using VisualC++ lines 1,2 and 3 compile. In clang and gcc, only 1 and 2 compile and line 3 gives an error (use of deleted copy constructor).

Question: Which compiler is right and why?

Try it here: [rextester](http://rextester.com/XPDYU27100)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it would make more sense to use  `my_map.emplace(3, std::move(my_moveable_3));` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map::insert` has (among others) the following overloads:

```
// 1.
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );

// 2. (since C++11)
template< class P >
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value );

// 3. (since C++17)
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type&& value );
```

The first overload obviously cannot be used with move-only types. But the second overload, while available in C++11, does not work with braces here because template argument deduction does not occur with braces (at least in C++11, not sure about later standards).

Both your first and second call to `insert` work in C++11 or later because the compiler knows the type, but the third fails.

C++17 adds another overload that works with braces and move-only types. Now as for why it works with certain compilers and not others, this is most likely due to diffences in the level of C++17 support, or compiler flags.

UPDATE: Just to make it painfully obvious: With using braces I mean using braces only (aggregate initialization or implicit constructor call), i.e. `insert({k,v})`, not `insert(pair<K,V>{k,v})`. In the latter case, the type is known and the templated overload can be selected even in C++11.

Comment: So what I'm getting from this is that it should compile, so VC was correct, right?

Comment: Yes, but note that the versions of GCC (5.4) and Clang (3.8) on the website you linked to were both released before C++17. As @Giggi pointed out, GCC 7.3 accepts the code. Unfortunately, I tried both GCC 6.3 and a Clang 6.0 pre-release in vain. (I'm not sure what libc++ version I have.)

Comment: Nothing has changed about function argument deduction since C++11: there’s just no type to deduce from braces.

Comment: @DavisHerring The last part is not true (and that's the entire point here): *Template* argument deduction from *braced-init-list* still does not work. Deducing a *known type* (here: `value_type &&`) from an overload set is a completely different story.

Comment: @ArneVogel: There isn’t any “deduction” that isn’t template argument deduction—determining how to interpret braces for a known type (for each candidate) is just part of overload resolution.  By “no type” I meant no *argument* type from which to deduce—sorry that wasn’t precise.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code with with g++ 7.3 and it compiles without error!

With clang++ 5.0.1 it doesn't compile.

I think that you are using a feature of the c++20 so the support is not yet ready on all compilers.

Comment: What C++20 feature would that be?